# How to install a Ruby gem on Arch Linux using Puppet?

Tags: arch-linux, bugs, gem

I've got [the following](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/cf94a48397bb2323bbecfd657b43d6fd748818c8/modules/travis_linter/manifests/init.pp):

```
class travis_linter {
  include shell

  package { 'travis-lint':
    ensure   => latest,
    provider => gem,
  }
}
```

When I try to [test it](https://github.com/l0b0/root/tree/cf94a48397bb2323bbecfd657b43d6fd748818c8#test), however, I get the following Puppet output:

```
==> default: Debug: Executing: '/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint'
==> default: Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint' returned 1: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
==> default:     wrong argument type nil (expected Regexp)
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Package[travis-lint]/ensure: change from absent to latest failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint' returned 1: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
==> default:     wrong argument type nil (expected Regexp)
```

Other possibly relevant output from the [full log file](http://pastebin.com/GgT3Vy1E):

```
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPuppet_gem: file /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem does not exist
Debug: /Package[puppet-lint]: Provider gem does not support features virtual_packages; not managing attribute allow_virtual
Debug: /Package[reek]: Provider gem does not support features virtual_packages; not managing attribute allow_virtual
Debug: /Package[travis-lint]: Provider gem does not support features virtual_packages; not managing attribute allow_virtual
```

Using `exec` (with `--backtrace` and `--debug`) instead of `package` results in the same error:

```
==> default: Debug: Executing: '/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: Exception `ArgumentError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:498 - couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:171 - LoadError
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: Exception `Resolv::DNS::Config::NXDomain' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:549 - _rubygems._tcp.api.rubygems.org
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: Exception `Resolv::DNS::Config::NXDomain' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:549 - _rubygems._tcp.api.rubygems.org.vagrant.vm
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: Exception `Resolv::ResolvError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:494 - DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.api.rubygems.org
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: Exception `TypeError' at /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:674 - wrong argument type nil (expected Regexp)
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:     wrong argument type nil (expected Regexp)
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:674:in `sub'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:674:in `check_that_user_bin_dir_is_in_path'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `initialize'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:104:in `new'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb:104:in `at'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:163:in `block in install'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:151:in `each'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:151:in `install'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:250:in `install_gem'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:300:in `block in install_gems'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:296:in `each'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:296:in `install_gems'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:203:in `execute'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command.rb:308:in `invoke_with_build_args'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:169:in `process_args'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:139:in `run'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:55:in `run'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns:   /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
==> default: Error: /usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint returned 1 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Travis_linter/Exec[/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --backtrace --debug travis-lint returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

I am able to run the exact same command manually:

```
[vagrant@archlinux ~]$ /usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint
Fetching: travis-lint-2.0.0.gem (100%)
WARNING:  You don't have /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed travis-lint-2.0.0
1 gem installed
```

Ditto [in a root shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252937/how-to-install-a-ruby-gem-on-arch-linux-using-puppet#comment436507_252937):

```
[vagrant@archlinux ~]$ sudo -s
root@archlinux:/home/vagrant# /usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint
WARNING:  You don't have /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed travis-lint-2.0.0
1 gem installed
```

And ditto in `sh`:

```
[vagrant@archlinux ~]$ sudo sh
sh-4.3# /usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint
WARNING:  You don't have /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed travis-lint-2.0.0
1 gem installed
```

Is something broken about running [`gem` 2.5.1](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12070) with [Puppet 4.3.1/4.3.2](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-5645)?

---

Finally some [findings](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12070#note-3)! It seems **`gem install` in an environment without the `HOME` variable defined [will fail](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/lib/rubygems/installer.rb#L674):**

```
unless !Gem.win_platform? && (path.include? user_bin_dir.sub(ENV['HOME'], '~'))
```

The ugly workaround:

```
exec { '/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint':
  environment => 'HOME=/root';
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you try to install it with the same parameters as Puppet?  Namely: `/usr/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri travis-lint`

Edit: FWIW I couldn't recreate your issue on CentOS 7.  I created a .pp file and did a puppet apply against it (using the latest Puppet Enterprise)

Comment: @muru I'm running `puppet` as root, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @muru Good point. I just tried, but the result was the same.

Comment: @l0b0 `gem` has `--backtrace` and `--debug` options that might be useful (when using `exec`).

Comment: If `check_that_user_bin_dir_is_in_path` means what I think it means, maybe you could try setting `PATH` to `/usr/bin:/bin`, etc.? Perhaps the error is because `PATH` is empty?

Comment: @l0b0 nice find. I suppose then that this would happen in various versions of ruby/gem